# azure Subscription " You are not eligible for an Azure subscription"

Tags: azure

I have signed up using my Gmail id for a free Azure subscription. After entering details and credit card information I have accepted terms & condition. Onclick of submitting I am getting the message `You are not eligible for an Azure subscription`
.

Comment: Please try in incognito window or clear all browsing data in your browser and try

Comment: I have tried in different browsers incognito window still facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please try in incognito window or clear all browsing data in your browser and try. Also this is what written in Microsoft support,

[image]

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4467267/can-t-sign-up-for-azure-in-azure-portal-or-azure-account-center

Comment: I have tried in different browsers incognito window still facing same issue. cross checked all details also everything seems alright still facinf same issue.

Comment: Also did you double check the Microsoft checklist which I have shared?

Answer (score 0):

The information that you provided for your Azure account profile (including contact email address, street address, and telephone number) should be correct and most importantly **You don't already have a Microsoft account that uses the same information**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/troubleshoot-azure-sign-up